# text alignment with a picture horizontally

Tags: graphics, minipage, tabularx

I am new to LaTeX and I am working with ShareLaTex. I started writing my Thesis for the University and I want to put some text alligned with the the top of the picture and with a space between the picture and the text. Specifically I want next to the image to be the text "Technical University of Crete". I have tried `\tabular` command and `\minspace` but without success. Here is my code.

```
<pre> <code>

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english , greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}



\graphicspath{{my_images/}}

\title{Βελτιστοποίηση πορείας και κυκλοφοριακής ροής μέσω αυτοματοποιημένης  αλλαγής λωρίδας αυτόματων οχημάτων σε αυτοκινητόδρομους}
\author{Αντώνιος Γεωργαντάς}
\date{Χανιά 2016}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{TUC} 
\end{figure}


\maketitle

\tableofcontents



 \end{document}
```

The picture's name is TUC.

Could you tell me how to put the text alligned exactly with the top of the picture?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably an Image will explain better in here.

Comment: So how can I fix the problem?Do you have any idea? I mean I have the picture in the left and I want a space in the right that the text will be perfectly alligned. Some other command?

Comment: Just give one option to `inputenc`, `utf8` is it.

Answer (score 2):

Is this more or less what you want? I used the `titling` package, which defines 4 hooks to insert commands within the `\maketitle` command:

- `\maketitlehooka`, used before the `_title` command,
- `\maketitlehookb`, between `\title` and `author`,
- `\maketitlehookc`, between `author` and `date`,
- `\maketitlehookd`, after `date`.

  ```
  \documentclass{report}
  \usepackage[english , greek]{babel}
  \usepackage[iso-8859-7,utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage{refstyle}
  \usepackage{ragged2e}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \graphicspath{{my_images/}}

  \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

  \usepackage{titling}
  \setlength\droptitle{-5cm}
  \renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\raisebox{-0.35\height}     {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{TUC}}\quad\sffamily \begin{tabular}{l}{\selectlanguage{english}{TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY OF CRETE}}\\[3ex]ΠΟΛΥΤΕΧΝΕΙΟ ΚΡΗΤΗΣ\end{tabular}\vskip 24ex}
  \renewcommand\maketitlehookb{\vskip 8ex}
  \renewcommand\maketitlehookc{\vfill}

  \title{Βελτιστοποίηση πορείας και κυκλοφοριακής ροής μέσω αυτοματοποιημένης αλλαγής λωρίδας αυτόματων οχημάτων σε αυτοκινητόδρομους}
  \author{Αντώνιος Γεωργαντάς}
  \date{Χανιά 2016}

  \begin{document}

  \maketitle

  \tableofcontents

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: Bernard this is exactly what I want! However, I want to live some space between the picture and the title of the Thesis, as well as some space between the title and my name. How could I accomplish that? Thank you

Comment: @bazooka: Please see my updated answer. I inserted three skips with  three `\maketitlehookx` (there are 4 of them  in all).